# Invalid syntax RCSwitch

Tags: python

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
```

That are the first lines in my script and I always get a

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python D2_on.py
File "D2_on.py", line 3
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But why? :\

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work, because your code is not Python. There is [`RCSwitch`](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/) for iOS (which is in Objective-C) and there is [`rc-switch`](https://code.google.com/p/rc-switch/) for Arduino and Raspberry Pi, which is in C++. As you are on a Raspberry Pi (`pi@raspberrypi`), I suspect it is the second one you are after.